# Scala: what do ":=" and "::=" operator do?

Tags: scala, operator-keyword

I'm pretty new with scala. I skimmed through the book and stumbled these two operators in code. What do they do ?

Comment: It depends on the type of the object on the left-hand side.

Comment: Well, I found the code and there have no explanation below or above it. It's just there

Comment: As Scala is strongly typed, you should be able to infer the type of the expression.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Syntactic Sugar

There is some syntactic sugar that applies when using operators in Scala.

Consider an operator `*`. When compiler encounters `a *= b`, it will check if method `*=` is defined on `a`, and call `a.*=(b)` if possible. Otherwise the expression will expand into `a = a.*(b)`.

However, any operator that ends with a `:` will have the right and left arguments swapped when converting to method invocation. So `a :: b` becomes `b.::(a)`. On the other hand `a ::= b` becomes `a = a.::(b)` which could be counter-intuitive due to the lack of the order reversal.

Because of the special meaning, it is not possible to define an operator `:`. So `:` is used in conjunction with other symbols, for example `:=`.

### Meaning of Operators

Operators in Scala are defined by the library writers, so they can mean different things.

`::` operator is usually used for list concatenation, and `a ::= b` means `take a, prepend b to it, and assign the result to a`.

`a := b` usually means `set the value of a to the value of b`, as opposed to `a = b` which will cause `the reference a to point to object b`.

Answer (score 4):

This calls the method `:` or `::` on the object at the left hand side, with the object at the right hand side as argument, and assigns the result to the variable at the left hand side.

```
foo ::= bar
```

Is equivalent to

```
foo = foo.::(bar)
```

See the documentation for the `:` or `::` method of the object's type.

(For collections, the `::` method appends an element to the beginning of the list.)

Comment: +1 to arnaud. [This question about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181745/understanding-infix-method-call-and-cons-operator-in-scala) **infix method call** could be helpful.

Comment: @arnaud576875 You should mention that it would first try to call the method called `::=` on `foo` if the static type of `foo` defines it, and then fall back to what you’ve described.