# Why can't I chain several Scala infix method calls

Tags: scala, infix-operator

I am working on a DSL and I've run into a problem with using methods as infix operators in a chain. I'll just try to explain it with some code. I have a trait `Term` and case classes `Literal` and `Variable` extending it. I want to construct a list of term instances using some operators.

```
case class Expr(val terms: List[Term]) {
 def +(v: String) = Expr(Literal(v) :: terms)
 def -->(func: List[String] => List[String]) = terms match {
  case Literal(v) :: ts => Expr(Variable(v, func) :: ts)
  case _ => throw new Exception("Can only apply function on literal")
 }
}

object foo {
 def bar(name: String) = Expr(Literal(name) :: Nil)
}

// some functions
val one = ... 
val all = ...

// works
foo bar "x"        
// res1: Expr = Expr(List(Literal(x)))

// works not
foo bar "x" --> all
// error: value --> is not a member of java.lang.String

// works
(foo bar "x") --> all 
// res1: Expr = Expr(List(Variable(x,<function1>)))
```

I would expect that this would be equivalent to `foo.bar("x").-->(all)` but the interpreter seems to see it as `foo.bar("x".-->(all))`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can find **operator precedence** here:

[Operator precedence in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922347/operator-precedence-in-scala)

According to first answer `-` has higher priority compared to letters. So compiler groups expression like this:

```
foo bar ("x" --> all)
```

If you will replace `-->` with something of lower priority (e.g. letters), then it should compile. For example:

```
foo bar "x" to all
```

You can also choose higher priority operator instead of `bar`. Something like `~~>` will do it, because `~` is special character and it has highest priority:

```
foo ~~> "x" --> all
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess seeing the operators as methods had me forget that they can have precedence.