# how to keep return value when logging in scala

Tags: scala, logging

When programming in java, I always log input parameter and return value of a method, but in scala, the last line of a method is the return value. so I have to do something like:

```
def myFunc() = {
  val rs = calcSomeResult()
  logger.info("result is:" + rs)
  rs
}
```

in order to make it easy, I write a utility:

```
class LogUtil(val f: (String) => Unit) {
 def logWithValue[T](msg: String, value: T): T = { f(msg); value }
}

object LogUtil {
  def withValue[T](f: String => Unit): ((String, T) => T) = new LogUtil(f).logWithValue _
}
```

Then I used it as:

```
val rs = calcSomeResult()
withValue(logger.info)("result is:" + rs, rs)
```

it will log the value and return it. it works for me,but seems wierd. as I am a old java programmer, but new to scala, I don't know whether there is a more idiomatic way to do this in scala.

---

thanks for your help, now I create a better util using Kestrel combinator metioned by romusz

```
object LogUtil {
  def kestrel[A](x: A)(f: A => Unit): A = { f(x); x }
  def logV[A](f: String => Unit)(s: String, x: A) = kestrel(x) { y => f(s + ": " + y)}
}
```

I add f parameter so that I can pass it a logger from slf4j, and the test case is:

```
class LogUtilSpec extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers {
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass())
  import LogUtil._

"LogUtil" should "print log info and keep the value, and the calc for value should only be called once" in {
  def calcValue = { println("calcValue"); 100 } // to confirm it's called only once 
  val v = logV(logger.info)("result is", calcValue)
  v should be === 100
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use AspectJ? Yes, its not Scala, that's true.

Answer (score 35):

What you're looking for is called Kestrel combinator (K combinator): `Kxy = x`. You can do all kinds of side-effect operations (not only logging) while returning the value passed to it. Read https://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/blob/master/2008-10-29/kestrel.markdown#readme

In Scala the simplest way to implement it is:

```
  def kestrel[A](x: A)(f: A => Unit): A = { f(x); x }
```

Then you can define your printing/logging function as:

```
def logging[A](x: A) = kestrel(x)(println)
def logging[A](s: String, x: A) = kestrel(x){ y => println(s + ": " + y) }
```

And use it like:

```
logging(1 + 2) + logging(3 + 4)
```

your example function becomes a one-liner:

```
def myFunc() = logging("result is", calcSomeResult())
```

If you prefer OO notation you can use implicits as shown in other answers, but the problem with such approach is that you'll create a new object every time you want to log something, which may cause performance degradation if you do it often enough. But for completeness, it looks like this:

```
implicit def anyToLogging[A](a: A) = new {
  def log = logging(a)
  def log(msg: String) = logging(msg, a)
}
```

Use it like:

```
def myFunc() = calcSomeResult().log("result is")
```

Comment: +1 for highlighting the added overhead of the OO solution when compared to the functional equivalent. I believe that the logging functionality must be used sparingly and in such scenarios syntactic convenience might take precedence over speed or memory use.

Comment: thanks for the knowledge of Kestrel combinator, I can have a better util now

Comment: To make it a little easier to accept functions producing any value and ignoring it: `def kestrel[A,B](x: A)(f: A => B): A = { f(x); x }`

Comment: Better yet: `def kestrel[A](x: A)(f: A => Any): A = { f(x); x }`

Answer (score 6):

You have the basic idea right--you just need to tidy it up a little bit to make it maximally convenient.

```
class GenericLogger[A](a: A) {
  def log(logger: String => Unit)(str: A => String): A = { logger(str(a)); a }
}
implicit def anything_can_log[A](a: A) = new GenericLogger(a)
```

Now you can

```
scala> (47+92).log(println)("The answer is " + _)
The answer is 139
res0: Int = 139
```

This way you don't need to repeat yourself (e.g. no `rs` twice).

Answer (score 6):

If you like a more generic approach better, you could define

```
implicit def idToSideEffect[A](a: A) = new {
  def withSideEffect(fun: A => Unit): A = { fun(a); a }
  def |!>(fun: A => Unit): A = withSideEffect(fun) // forward pipe-like
  def tap(fun: A => Unit): A = withSideEffect(fun) // public demand & ruby standard
}
```

and use it like

```
calcSomeResult() |!> { rs => logger.info("result is:" + rs) }

calcSomeResult() tap println
```

Comment: Rather than a weird symbol, you can in the same number of characters define `tap`, which does exactly the same thing in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks, @RexKerr. I’ve searched a bit for a name but didn’t think of Ruby.

Comment: Note that in Scala 2.10 you can [value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) to avoid some overhead: `implicit class TapOnValue[A](val v: A) extends AnyVal { ... }`

Answer (score 6):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the chaining operation [`tap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#tap[U](f:A=%3EU):A) can be used to apply a side effect (in this case some logging) on any value while returning the original value:

> def tap[U](f: (A) => U): A

For instance:

```
scala> val a = 42.tap(println)
42
a: Int = 42
```

or in our case:

```
import scala.util.chaining._

def myFunc() = calcSomeResult().tap(x => logger.info(s"result is: $x"))
```

Comment: It's a pity we have to import the package in order to use it because this feature is extremely useful.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you already have a base class for all you loggers:

```
abstract class Logger {
  def info(msg:String):Unit
}
```

Then you could extend String with the `@@` logging method:

```
object ExpressionLog {
  // default logger
  implicit val logger = new Logger { 
    def info(s:String) {println(s)}
  }

  // adding @@ method to all String objects
  implicit def stringToLog (msg: String) (implicit logger: Logger) = new {
    def @@ [T] (exp: T) = {
      logger.info(msg + " = " + exp)
      exp
    }
  }
}
```

To use the logging you'd have to import members of  `ExpressionLog` object and then you could easily log expressions using the following notation:

```
import ExpressionLog._

def sum (a:Int, b:Int) = "sum result" @@ (a+b)
val c = sum("a" @@ 1, "b" @@2)
```

Will print:

> ```
> a = 1
> b = 2
> sum result = 3
> ```

This works because every time when you call a `@@` method on a `String` compiler realises that `String` doesn't have the method and silently converts it into an object with anonymous type that has the `@@` method defined (see `stringToLog`). As part of the conversion compiler picks the desired logger as an [implicit parameter](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/114), this way you don't have to keep passing on the logger to the `@@` every time yet you retain full control over which logger needs to be used every time.

As far as precedence goes when `@@` method is used in infix notation it has the [highest priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922347/operator-precedence-in-scala) making it easier to reason about what will be logged.

So what if you wanted to use a different logger in one of your methods? This is very simple:

```
import ExpressionLog.{logger=>_,_}  // import everything but default logger
// define specific local logger 
// this can be as simple as: implicit val logger = new MyLogger
implicit val logger = new Logger { 
  var lineno = 1
  def info(s:String) {
    println("%03d".format(lineno) + ": " + s) 
    lineno+=1
  }
}

// start logging
def sum (a:Int, b:Int) = a+b
val c = "sum result" @@ sum("a" @@ 1, "b" @@2)
```

Will output:

> ```
> 001: a = 1
> 002: b = 2
> 003: sum result = 3
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Compiling all the answers, pros and cons, I came up with this (context is a Play application):

```
import play.api.LoggerLike

object LogUtils {

implicit class LogAny2[T](val value : T) extends AnyVal {

    def @@(str : String)(implicit logger : LoggerLike) : T = {
        logger.debug(str);
        value
    }

    def @@(f : T => String)(implicit logger : LoggerLike) : T = {
        logger.debug(f(value))
        value
    }
}
```

As you can see, LogAny is an AnyVal so there shouldn't be any overhead of new object creation.

You can use it like this:

```
scala> import utils.LogUtils._
scala> val a = 5
scala> val b = 7
scala> implicit val logger = play.api.Logger

scala> val c = a + b @@ { c => s"result of $a + $b = $c" }
c: Int = 12
```

Or if you don't need a reference to the result, just use:

```
scala> val c = a + b @@ "Finished this very complex calculation"
c: Int = 12
```

Any downsides to this implementation?

***Edit:***

I've made this available with some improvements in a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/liorgonnen/81fa8c428601c263d7e9)