# Equivalent to Ruby's #tap method in Scala

Tags: scala, combinatory-logic

Ruby has a method that allows us to observe a pipeline of values, without modifying the underlying value:

```
# Ruby
list.tap{|o| p o}.map{|o| 2*o}.tap{|o| p o}
```

Is there such a method in Scala? I believe this is called a Kestrel Combinator, but can't be sure.

Comment: Did you google scala kestrel combinator?  Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9673294/1339987

Comment: @djechlin No, searched in "To mock a mockingbird" and wrote Kestrel, but forgot to Google, duh. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: There is [also whole blogpost dedicated to the use of the kestrel in scala](http://debasishg.blogspot.ru/2009/09/side-effects-with-kestrel-in-scala.html). Unfortunately, scala has no such thing out-of-the-box.

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil I can't follow your sarcasm - *did* that actually help?

Comment: For reference, the idiomatic version in 2.10 using the Ruby notation would be `implicit class TapAnyone[A](val value: A) extends AnyVal { def tap[B](f: A => B) = { f(value); value } }`

Comment: @djechlin Sorry, I wasn't even trying to be sarcastic. I tried to explain that I looked in my book, and forgot to Google before coming here. Sorry for the confusion. Yes, your reference did help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one implementation on github:  https://gist.github.com/akiellor/1308190

Reproducing here:

```
import collection.mutable.MutableList
import Tap._

class Tap[A](any: A) {
  def tap(f: (A) => Unit): A = {
    f(any)
    any
  }
}

object Tap {
  implicit def tap[A](toTap: A): Tap[A] = new Tap(toTap)
}

MutableList[String]().tap({m:MutableList[String] =>
  m += "Blah"
})

MutableList[String]().tap(_ += "Blah")

MutableList[String]().tap({ l =>
  l += "Blah"
  l += "Blah"
})
```

Comment: That would be good if you add same version with implicit class, cause implicit conversion called tap[a] and method tap in class Tap, can be a bit obscure

Comment: For Scala 2.13+ see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54610963/637754