# Avoiding the variable in "val x = foo; bar(x); x"

Tags: scala, variables, idioms

Often I have functions like this:

```
{
  val x = foo;
  bar(x);
  x
}
```

For example, `bar` is often something like `Log.debug`.

Is there a shorter, idiomatic way how to run it? For example, a built-in function like

```
def act[A](value: A, f: A => Any): A = { f(value); value }
```

so that I could write just `act(foo, bar _)`.

Comment: this is what side effects makes to people =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understood the question correctly, but if i do, then i often use this method taken from the Spray toolkit:

```
def make[A, B](obj: A)(f: A => B): A = { f(obj); obj }
```

then you can write the following things:

```
utils.make(new JobDataMap()) { map =>
  map.put("phone", m.phone)
  map.put("medicine", m.medicine.name)
  map.put("code", utils.genCode)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your `act` function as written seems perfectly idiomatic to me. I don't know of a built-in way to do it, but I'd just throw this kind of thing in a "commons" or "utils" project that I use everywhere.

If the bar function is usually the same (e.g. Log.debug) then you could also make a specific wrapper function for that.  For instance:

```
def withDebug[A](prefix: String)(value: A)(implicit logger: Logger): A = {
  logger.debug(prefix + value)
  value
}
```

which you can then use as follows:

```
implicit val loggerI = logger

def actExample() {
  // original method
  val c = act(2 + 2, logger.debug)

  // a little cleaner?
  val d = withDebug("The sum is: ") {
      2 + 2
    }
  }
```

Or for even more syntactic sugar:

```
object Tap {
  implicit def toTap[A](value: A): Tap[A] = new Tap(value)
}

class Tap[A](value: A) {

  def tap(f: A => Any): A = {
    f(value)
    value
  }

  def report(prefix: String)(implicit logger: Logger): A = {
    logger.debug(prefix + value)
    value
  }
}

object TapExample extends Logging {
  import Tap._
  implicit val loggerI = logger

  val c = 2 + 2 tap { x => logger.debug("The sum is: " + x) }

  val d = 2 + 2 report "The sum is: "

  assert(d == 4)
}
```

Where `tap` takes an arbitrary function, and `report` just wraps a logger.  Of course you could add whatever other commonly used taps you like to the `Tap` class.

Comment: Ah, I agree that "tap" is a nice name for it.  Also it looks like all of these solutions are well described in [Equivalent to Ruby's #tap method in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742060/equivalent-to-rubys-tap-method-in-scala) and [how to keep return value when logging in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671620/how-to-keep-return-value-when-logging-in-scala)

Answer (score 0):

Note that Scala already includes a syntactically heavyweight version:

```
foo match { case x => bar(x); x }
```

but creating the shorter version (`tap` in Ruby--I'd suggest using the same name) can have advantages.

Comment: This seems longer than the original `{ val x = foo; bar(x); x }`.

Comment: @PetrPudlák - It is, which is why the original is preferred in most cases.