# Scala way to write lisp-like progn?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, lisp

Is there in Scala some language construction like lisp's `progn`?
Thanks!

Comment: Please add pseudo scala code with such `progn` you want to evaluate and the result of evaluation. Note that in scala `{a; b; c}` returns result of `c`.

Comment: Or describe what `progn` does with natural language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, curly braces.

```
progn evaluates forms, in the order in which they are given.

The values of each form but the last are discarded.

Examples:

 (progn) =>  NIL
 (progn 1 2 3) =>  3
 (progn (values 1 2 3)) =>  1, 2, 3
 (setq a 1) =>  1
 (if a
      (progn (setq a nil) 'here)
      (progn (setq a t) 'there)) =>  HERE
 a =>  NIL
```

Now the same, but in scala:

```
scala> {}

// Unit is not written explicitly, but it is here
scala> {1; 2; 3}
// warnings omitted
// res1: Int = 3

scala> {(1, 2, 3)}
// res2: (Int, Int, Int) = (1,2,3)

// no direct analog for setq, skipping other examples
```

And to ensure you that *evaluates forms, **in the order in which they are given***:

```
scala> {println('1'); println('2'); println('3')}
1
2
3
```

Comment: One more noob question:) What about PROG1, PGOG2?

Comment: I doubt there is built in mechanisms for both. For PROG1 there is an analog (in some sense) -- [function commonly called `tap` (aka kestrel combinator)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16742060/298389)

Comment: @om-nom-nom Both seem to be very easy to implement with Scala macros.

Comment: @ghik yeah, but I don't think it is really needed, ordinary scala possibilities will do the job