# How to write clear code with logging?

Tags: scala, oop, haskell, functional-programming

logging is cluttering my "beautiful" clean simple short code.
instead of a simple

```
def mymethod = dosomething // scala
```

my code is also having also all these nasty logging statements which and immediately i have to add new lines and curly braces to `mymethod`.
now i don't like `AOP` it would just make clear code --> unclear.
anyway to get over this? I have when simple code turns to less simple, but i also need logging. help.

how to make this code clear simple short and also with logging?

Comment: That is some nasty way to formulate a simple question.

Comment: What does this have to do with haskell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Kestrel combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16742060/298389) is commonly used for this:

```
def mymethod = dosomething.tap(x => log.info(s"I've done ... and got $x"))
```

If you need to do this for any method, there is scala virtualized, which allows to overload some of the language concepts, including method calls, I guess. Plus, somebody might propose to look at the macro, but I'm not competent enough to make this assumptions.

Answer (score 7):

A typical approach in functional programming would be to add a higher-order logging combinator.

```
log :: IO a -> String -> IO a 
log f s = do
    v <- f
    print ("My message: " ++ s)
    return v
```

Such a wrapper augments evaluation of a function with a log message.
The general pattern is `\x y -> .. something with y .. return x`