# Are there any types with side-effecting methods that return the original type?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, side-effects

Often I find myself wanting to chain a side-effecting function to the end of another method call in a more functional-looking way, but I don't want to transform the original type to `Unit`. Suppose I have a `read` method that searches a database for a record, returning `Option[Record]`.

```
def read(id: Long): Option[Record] = ...
```

If `read` returns `Some(record)`, then I might want to cache that value and move on. I could do something like this:

```
read(id).map { record =>
    // Cache the record
    record
}
```

But, I would like to avoid the above code and end up with something more like this to make it more clear as to what's happening:

```
read(id).withSideEffect { record =>
    // Cache the record
}
```

Where `withSideEffect` returns the same value as `read(id)`. After searching high and low, I can't find any method on any type that does something like this. The closest solution I can come up with is using implicit magic:

```
implicit class ExtendedOption[A](underlying: Option[A]) {
    def withSideEffect(op: A => Unit): Option[A] = {
        underlying.foreach(op)
        underlying
    }
}
```

Are there any Scala types I may have overlooked with methods like this one? And are there are any potential design flaws from using such a method?

Comment: Scala does have support for "singleton types" (not to be confused with objects), which is the type corresponding to a specific instance. For example the method `def f(a: A): a.type` *must* return the provided instance of `A`.

Comment: Design looks fine to me, I use this myself.

Comment: Have you thought about [Kestrel combinators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671620/how-to-keep-return-value-when-logging-in-scala)? The example uses it for logging but you can easily adapt it to caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Future.andThen` ([scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@andThen[U](pf:PartialFunction[scala.util.Try[T],U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T])) takes a side-effect and returns a future of the current value to facilitate fluent chaining.

The return type is not `this.type`.

See also [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16742060/1296806) about tap.

Comment: +1 for the reference to tap. That seems exactly suited to the OP's need

Answer (score 0):

You can use scalaz for "explicit annotation" of side-effectful functions. In scalaz 7.0.6 it's IO monad: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/IO+Monad.html

It's deprecated in scalaz 7.1. I would do something like that with Task

```
val readAndCache = Task.delay(read(id)).map(record => cacheRecord(record); record)
readAndCache.run // Run task for it's side effects
```

Comment: Is there any information out there about this deprecation? It's not annotated or documented as such in the source.

Comment: Can't find it now. It was a discussion in mailing list that Task should be replacement for IO. But looks like it didn't happen in 7.1. They both are very similar semantically.