# Is there a short version for modify and reasign a variable in Scala?

Tags: scala

I was wondering if there is a shorter version of

```
var longVariableName: MyType = MyTyp("Value")
longVariableName = longVariableName.addSomething("added")

case class MyType(value: String) {
  def addSomething(add: String): MyType = ???
}
```

Maybe something like

```
var longVariableName: MyType = MyType("Value")
longVariableName = _.addSomething("extended")
```

Would be so nice :)
Thank you

Comment: I guess in general answer is **no** because scala discourages use of mutability (for a great good). Though, [you can add such functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671620/how-to-keep-return-value-when-logging-in-scala/9673294#9673294)

Answer (score 5):

I guess the easiest way would be:

```
val longVariableName = MyTyp("Value")
.addSomething("added")
.addSomethingElse("other")
.addSomeMore("stuff")
```

As long as each method returns the base type (i.e. "Builder" pattern), you can further chain calls.
In this way, you use a value (not a variable) and given that each method call returns a new instance of the case class, it's immutable, with no side-effect.

Furthermore, case classes support a builder-like pattern with the copy method, which allows to "add" information down the road in an immutable way.

Something like this:

```
case class Player(name:String, rank:Option[String] = None) { 
    def withRank(rank:Int)= this.copy(rank=Some(s"top${100-rank}%")) 
}

val player = Player("sparky").withRank(5)
```

(Or multi-line)

```
val player = Player("sparky")
.withRank(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a `+` method for your case class:

```
case class MyType(value: String) {
    def +(add: String) = MyType(value + add)
}

var longVariableName: MyType = MyType("Value")
longVariableName += "extended"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the copy method without defining anything else.

```
case class MyType(value: String, otherValue: String, otherOthervalue: String)

val longName = MyType("Value","OtherValue","OtherOtherValue")
val longerName = longName.copy(value=longName.value+"extended")
```

Comment: Forgot to add the boilerplate "don't use vars"