# Scala: Filling an Array of Random Bytes

Tags: arrays, scala

This is the code that I currently use

```
val bytes = new Array[Byte](20)
scala.util.Random.nextBytes(bytes)
sendAndReceive(bytes)
```

Is there a way to turn that into a one-liner? For example, if it is an Integer array I can do

```
sendAndReceive(Array.fill(20){scala.util.Random.nextInt(9)}
```

Replacing `nextInt` with `nextBytes` does not work because nextBytes takes an `Array[Byte]` as parameter, instead of returning a single Byte.

Answer (score 11):

How about manually doing it? `Byte` range is from -128 to 127. That gives us:

```
Array.fill(20)((scala.util.Random.nextInt(256) - 128).toByte)
```

You can also write an implicit if you need it at multiple places.

```
implicit class ExtendedRandom(ran: scala.util.Random) {
  def nextByte = (ran.nextInt(256) - 128).toByte
}

Array.fill(20)(scala.util.Random.nextByte)
```

As @Chris Martin suggested, you can also use `nextBytes` in an implicit class.

```
implicit class ExtendedRandom(ran: scala.util.Random) {
  def nextByteArray(size: Int) = {
    val arr = new Array[Byte](size)
    ran.nextBytes(arr)
    arr
  }
}

scala.util.Random.nextByteArray(20)
```

Comment: If you're going to use an implicit class, why would you still avoid `Random.nextBytes`?

Comment: @ChrisMartin true, I'll add that.

Comment: Am looking at a one-liner, if possible :)

Comment: @hanxue My first solution is a one-liner. The other two are implicits that you define seperatly and just have to import where needed. Then the solutions are also one-liners. This is useful when you need them at multiple places.

Answer (score 8):

There's the [Kestrel combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9673294/402884):

```
def kestrel[A](x: A)(f: A => Unit): A = { f(x); x }
```

With it you can write:

```
sendAndReceive(kestrel(Array.fill[Byte](20)(0))(Random.nextBytes))
```