# Scala wrapper for fluent sideeffects

Tags: scala

I am looking for something in scala to write the following code in a more compact way:

```
def getSomething():X = {
  val result = compute(...)
  println(result)
  result
}
```

I am thinking of something like that:

```
def getSomething():X = {
  MagicWrapper(compute(...)).do(println)
}
```

so that do is executed but the original value is returned. sounds like such a thing should exist somewhere but I could not found anything.

Comment: Sounds like a [Kestrel combinator](http://combinators.info/#kestrels)

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek but... but that's *ruby* :O

Comment: @Zoltán Oh well, it's readable enough and [there are other questions and answers addressing it in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9673294/1180426) :)

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek add it as answer and I accept it, if you want

Comment: @wrm It seems that current answer already covers it, even if the ties to combinatorial logic are not explicitly mentioned. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the extend-my-library pattern:

```
implicit class SideEffectPassthrough[A](val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  def se(sideEffectFunction: A => Unit): A = {
    sideEffectFunction(a)
    a
  }
}

def compute(a: Int) = a + 2 + 3
val x = compute(1).se(println)
// x: Int = 6
```

The compiler will do the wrapping for you, making the syntax cleaner.  (However, note that when we add `extends AnyVal`, we are actually ensuring that the compiler will rewrite this code so that it doesn't literally do any wrapping; instead it will create a static function to handle the behavior, which means less runtime overhead since no wrapper object will need to be instantiated.)

The `sideEffectFunction` argument of `se` can be any arbitrary function, as long as it takes as it's argument the result of the preceding expression:

```
val y = compute(1).se { r =>
  println("Performing a side effect now!")
  println(r)
}
// y: Int = 6
```

---

Just for the sake of completeness, here is a different way to accomplish the same goal:

```
def printAndReturn[A](block: => A): A = {
  val result = block
  println(result)
  result
}

val x = printAndReturn(1+2+3)
// x: Int = 6

val y = printAndReturn {
    val a = 1 + 2
    a + 3
}
// y: Int = 6
```

The argument `block` can be any arbitrary expression, including any arbitrary block of code.  Notice that it is passed by name, so it is evaluated inside `se`.