# Play 2.0 form - field "verifying" method is not a member

Tags: scala, validation, playframework-2.0

Practicing what is written here: [ScalaForms](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaForms), I have created the following form:

```
  val personCreationForm = Form(
    tuple (
        "name" -> nonEmptyText,
        "age" -> number verifying (min(0), max(100))       /*ERROR*/
    ) verifying ("Wrong entry", result => result match {
      case (name, age) => true
    })
  )
```

However, the error on `verifying` states that `value verifying is not a member of (java.lang.String, play.api.data.Mapping[Int])`.

Working with `mapping` instead of `tuple`, as in the referenced example, makes no difference. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Scala [operators precedence rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922347/operator-precedence-in-scala), methods starting with a letter have a lower precedence than others so when you write:

```scala
"age" -> number verifying (min(0), max(100))
```

The compiler builds the following expression:

```scala
("age" -> number) verifying (min(0), max(100))
```

Which is not what you want! You can rewrite it as follows:

```scala
"age" -> number.verifying(min(0), max(100))
"age" -> (number verifying (min(0), max(100)))
```

And the current Play documentation is wrong. Thanks for catching it!

Comment: Two years ago and the documentation is still wrong.  It also doesn't seem to solve the "name" -> text verifying(required) documentation compile error.

Comment: The up to date documentation is correct: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms