# DSL in scala to write chain comparisons such as a < b <= c

Tags: scala, comparison

I would like to write the following in Scala:

```
def method(a: Float, b: Float, c: Float) = {
  if( a < b <= c) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Currently, this is not valid. Indeed, `a < b` returns a Boolean, which for comparison purposes is wrapped by a `booleanWrapper`. The compiler then complains that c is of type `Float` and not `Boolean`, so it does not compare `b` to `c` at all.

Would it be possible to use implicit classes, methods and value classes to be able to achieve this?

For now, I have only been able to do the following:

```
class Less(val previous: Boolean, last: Float) {
  def <=(other: Float): Less = new Less(previous && last <= other, other)
  def <(other: Float): Less = new Less(previous && last < other, other)
}
implicit def f(v: Float): Less = {
  new Less(true, v)
}
implicit def lessToBoolean(f: Less): Boolean = {
  f.previous
}

def method(a: Float, b: Float, c: Float) = {
  if( f(a) < b <= c) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Any way to remove this f using standard tricks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do macros make naturally chained comparisons possible in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450324/do-macros-make-naturally-chained-comparisons-possible-in-scala)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can emulate this with implicits and custom operators.
Here is a short example:

```
implicit class FloatWrapper(n:Float) {
  def :<(that:Float) = ResultAndLastItem(n<that, that)
  def :>(that:Float) = ResultAndLastItem(n>that, that)
  def :=(that:Float) = ResultAndLastItem(n==that, that)
  // insert more comparison operations here
}

case class ResultAndLastItem(result:Boolean, lastItem:Float) extends FloatWrapper(lastItem) {
  // insert boolean operations here
  // boolean operations should return another instance of ResultAndLastItem (?)
}

implicit def toBoolean(r:ResultAndLastItem):Boolean = r.result
```

Here is an example usage in the REPL:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_45).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

implicit class FloatWrapper(n:Float) {
  def :<(that:Float) = ResultAndLastItem(n<that, that)
  def :>(that:Float) = ResultAndLastItem(n>that, that)
  def :=(that:Float) = ResultAndLastItem(n==that, that)
  // insert more comparison operations here
}

case class ResultAndLastItem(result:Boolean, lastItem:Float) extends FloatWrapper(lastItem) {
  // insert boolean operations here
  // boolean operations should return another instance of ResultAndLastItem (?)
}

implicit def toBoolean(r:ResultAndLastItem):Boolean = r.result

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

warning: there were 1 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
defined class FloatWrapper
defined class ResultAndLastItem
toBoolean: (r: ResultAndLastItem)Boolean

scala> if(2 :< 3 :< 4) "yay" else "nope"
res0: String = yay

scala> if(2 :< 3 :< 3) "nope" else "yay"
res1: String = yay
```

Remarks:

- You can easily add more comparison operators, such as `:<=`.
- The usage of custom operators is required because this forces the compiler to use the `implicit class` above, instead of the built-in default operator for `Float`s.
- It is hard to make my example more generic, in order to allow for all comparable types, such as `Double`, `Int`, or custom types. The reason why this is hard is because the `implicit class FloatWrapper` cannot require further `implicit` arguments - implicits cannot be nested. (Or more precisely, they can, syntactically, but then the compiler won't pick them for implicit resolution.)
- As an optimization, you might want to consider adding boolean shortcuts, i.e. when an expression is already known to be `false`, it is not necessary to evaluate the remaining comparisons.

  - This becomes tricky when you also add boolean operators, such as `||` or `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without explicit wrapping if you use standard types that have methods `<` and `<=`. If you however would provide your own types you could do it.

```
def method(a:SpecialFloat, b:SpecialFloat, c:SpecialFloat)

implicit class SpecialFloat(v:Float) extends AnyVal {

  def < (other:Float) = ??? 
  def <= (other:Float) = ???
}
```

That way you can implement the methods in any way you like. Calling `method(1f, 2f, 3f)` would automatically convert them into `SpecialFloat` instances ([more information about the `extends AnyVal`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html)).