# Does Scala have a function application operator?

Tags: scala, haskell, f#, functional-programming

F# has the pipeline operators:

```fs
arg |> func // or arg2 |> func arg1, as opposed to func arg1 arg2
func <| arg
```

Haskell has the `$` operator:

```hs
func $ arg -- or func1 $ func2 arg, as opposed to func1 (func2 arg)
```

They're mostly used to increase readability by de-cluttering the function calls.

Is there a similar operator in Scala?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is not.  You can easily define your own, however.

```
implicit class PipeEverything[A](val underlying: A) extends AnyVal {
  def |>[B](f: A => B) = f(underlying)
}
```

Comment: I should probably mention that `$` is right-associative and not only lets you pass in single arguments, but entire expressions as a parameter

Comment: @ElectricCoffee If you want right-associativity, call it `$:`. `|>` is already lowest precedence, except for letters (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922347/operator-precedence-in-scala).

Comment: @ElectricCoffee - You can always put an expression on the left; you just need parentheses or braces.  If you append a `:` to a symbolic method name, it will be right-associative.  So `|:` would be a right-associative `|>`.

Comment: @RexKerr The whole point of the `$` is to REMOVE parentheses, so having to add them would render it pointless

Comment: @ElectricCoffee - There can be other reasons to prefer the argument first (e.g. `(xs.head + 2) |> { y => (y,y) }`).  "I want Scala to look like Haskell" is a motivation that will leave you disappointed sooner or later.  (As will "I want Haskell to look like Scala", etc..)

Comment: oh but I don't want one to look like the other; I just want the convenience of not having to type more than I absolutely need to

Comment: @ElectricCoffee - "Not having to type more than I absolutely need to" is more of a Haskell design goal than a Scala one.  Consistency with other languages' syntax and readability are higher up on Scala's list.

Answer (score 1):

Scala does not have this operator in the standard library.

[Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) brings the thrush operator:

```scala
arg |> method
```

If you prefer [Cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) to Scalaz, you need the [Mouse](https://github.com/typelevel/mouse) companion library to get the same operator.