# Scala infix type aliasing for >2 type parameters?

Tags: scala, scalaz, type-alias

I know in Scala, you can do `type ===>[A, B] = Map[A, B]` and then you can use infix notation to define `def foo: String ===> Int` which is same as saying `def foo: Map[String, Int]`. Is there any way to exploit this infix notation to create types with >2 arguments? For example, I want something like this:

`type A ~> B ~~~> C` to be an alias of say `Map[A, Pair[B, C]]` ?

Is there anyway I can write something line this:

`type A to B -> C` as alias for `(A, B, C)` type?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Interestingly [operator precedence as defined for symbolic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922347/operator-precedence-in-scala?answertab=active#tab-top) doesn't seem to hold for symbolic type aliases. Instead infix type aliases are always evaluated left associative:

```
type -[A,B] = Map[A,B] 
type /[A,B] = Map[A,B] // '/' has higher precedence than '-' as an operator
classOf[A - B / C] // Class[/[-[A,B],C]]
classOf[A / B - C] // Class[-[/[A,B],C]]
```

Unfortunately that means it will never be possible to do what you ask for without parentheses like this:

```
classOf[A - (B / C)] // Class[-[A,/[B,C]]
```

So the closest answer is the following:

```
type ~>[A,B] = Map[A,B]
type ~~~>[A,B] = Pair[A,B]
classOf[A ~> (B ~~~> C)] // Map[A,Pair[B,C]]
```

Ommitting the parentheses will only be possible if you use right associative aliases (ending with `:`)

```
type ~:[A,B] = Map[A,B]
type ~~~:[A,B] = Pair[A,B]
classOf[A ~: B ~~~: C] // Map[A,Pair[B,C]]
```

Again, unfortunately since all type aliases have the same precedence it is not possible to mix right and left associative aliases without parentheses.

Concerning the second part of your question: `(A,B,C)` is syntactic sugar for `Tuple3[A,B,C]` which is a type with three parameters. As infix types only take two parameters, I'm afraid that I believe there is no way to represent this type solely with infix types. You would always end up with nested two parameter types (e.g. `(A,(B,C))` or `((A,B),C)`.

Comment: Great clarification. Didn't realise until your answer that the precedence was not the same!

Comment: Is it possible to achieve `A as B ~> C` to mean `(A, B, C)`?

Comment: @wrick: I don't believe this is possible on the type level. Infix types can only take two type parameters but (A,B,C) has three. Only ((A,B),C) or (A,(B,C)) are possible IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no. `A ~> B ~> C` cannot mean `Map[A, Pair[B, C]]`.

It could be made to mean `Map[A, Map[B, C]]`, though, or `Pair[A, Pair[B, C]]`.

Comment: What if I use two symbols e.g. `A ~> B ==> C` ?

Comment: That works, provided you get the precedence right for these infix “type constructors”, such that your example means `Map[A, Pair[B, C]]` and not `Pair[Map[A, B], C]`. Be sure to check section 6.12.3 of the Scala Language Specification.

Comment: `A ~> B ~> C` can not be made to mean `Map[A,Map[B,C]]`. Neither can anything without parentheses be made to mean `Map[A,Pair[B,C]]`. See my answer.