# Scala - tuple3 - syntactic sugar

Tags: scala, tuples

What is the syntactic sugar equivalent of following syntax:

```
List[Tuple2[String, Int]]  // Base
List[String Tuple2 Int]  // Syntactic sugar
```

for Tuple3? E.g.:

```
List[Tuple3[String, Float, Int]]  // Base
```

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23490562/757071. Infix is only for two parameters

Comment: Thanks! I asked because IntelliJ highlighted this part of code and said that sugar syntax is available. So after reading post sent by @johny I changed it to List[(String, Float, Int)]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This makes no sense. Infix syntax *by definition* works only for arity 2. That's not something special to Scala, that's not even special to programming, that's how it has always been and how it will always be. Infix operators are called infix operators because they sit in between their two operands. How can one operator sit in between three operands? You would need a two-part operator to sit in the two spaces between the three operands. Such operators do exist, they are called *ternary* operators, but it's not quite trivial to devise a syntax for using them interchangeably with prefix syntax, like Scala does.

Note, however, that there *is* syntactic sugar for what you are asking about:

```
List[Tuple2[String, Int]]  // Base
List[(String, Int)]  // Syntactic sugar

List[Tuple3[String, Float, Int]]  // Base
List[(String, Float, Int)]  // Syntactic sugar
```