# Scala - defining own infix operators

Tags: scala, operators, implicit-conversion, infix-notation, infix-operator

Methods taking a single argument can be written as an infix operators in Scal. I.e. adding `*(other:C) = foo(this, other)` to class C, will allow us to write `c1 * c2` instead of foo(c1,c2). But is there a way to define infix operators on existing classes that you cannot modify?

E.g. if I wanted to write `c1 + c2` instead of `xor(c1,c2)`, where `c1,c2:Array[Byte]`, I obviously cannot modify the Array-Class.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890507/creating-infix-operators-in-scala) and tried

```
implicit class Bytearray(a1:Array[Byte]) extends Anyval {
    def +(a2:Array[Byte]) = xor(a1,a2)
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work (`c1 + c2`).

> Type mismatch, expected:String, actual:Array[Byte]

I thought that perhaps the issue was my using `+`, so I exchanged it for `xor`
 but `c1 xor c2` only lead to

> Cannot resolve symbol xor

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Interesting. I had a `class Foo` with an `object Foo` defined below it, containing the implicit class. This lead to the aforementioned errors.

*However*, deleting the object and instead putting the implicit class into a `trait BytearrayHandling` and then extending it (`class Foo extends BytearrayHandling`) seems to work. Why is that?

Comment: Implicit class has to be a part of some kind of object, which you than have to import. 

Also it will help if you post the full code of what you tried.

Comment: Why can "some kind of object" not be the companion object (please see edit above)? Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: It can, but you still have to import it in the context where your implicit will be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be straight forward with the normal declaration of extension methods:

```
implicit class ByteArrayOps(private val a1: Array[Byte]) extends AnyVal {
  def + (a2: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = 
    (a1 zip a2).map { case (x, y) => (x ^ y).toByte }
}

"foo".getBytes + "bar".getBytes  // Array(4, 14, 29)
```

---

However be aware that sometimes you will run into this:

> Type mismatch, expected:String, actual: X

This is because of an implicit conversion kicking in that allows you to `+` anything by converting it to a String. I have [given](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-194) [up](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1931) [trying](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7327) [to understand](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8229) how to deactivate it. It will finally go in Scala 2.12 if I'm not mistaken.

As eugener pointed out, this error message may indicate that you haven't actually imported your extension method (implicit conversion). For example:

```
object MyStuff {
  implicit class ByteArrayOps(private val a1: Array[Byte]) extends AnyVal {
    def + (a2: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = 
      (a1 zip a2).map { case (x, y) => (x ^ y).toByte }
  }
}

"foo".getBytes + "bar".getBytes  // error
```

gives:

```
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Byte]
 required: String
              "foo".getBytes + "bar".getBytes
                                     ^
```

because of this `Predef` conversion. After you `import MyStuff.ByteArrayOps`, it works.

Comment: Are you sure it's impossible to use +? See my answer which works (for me at least!) :) I'm using Scala 2.11.6.

Comment: It's not impossible, it may just be blocked if you require another implicit conversion. I update the text.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
class ByteArray(self: Array[Byte]) {
  def +(other: Array[Byte]) = Array[Byte](1, 2, 3) // replace with your code
}

implicit def byteArrayPlus(self: Array[Byte]) = new ByteArray(self)

Array[Byte](0, 1, 2) + Array[Byte](0, 2, 3)
```

the last line of which should yield `Array(1, 2, 3)`.