# How to declare an abstract function in Inox

Tags: leon

I'm proving certain properties on elliptic curves and for that I rely on some functions that deal with field operations. However, I don't want Inox to reason about the implementation of these functions but to just assume certain properties on them.

Say for instance I'm proving that the addition of points `p1 = (x1,y1) and p2 = (x2,y2)` is commutative. For implementing the addition of points I need a function that implements addition over its components (i.e. the elements of a field).

The addition will have the following shape:

```
val addFunction = mkFunDef(addID)() { case Seq() => 
    val args: Seq[ValDef] = Seq("f1" :: F, "f2" :: F)  
    val retType: Type = F
    val body: Seq[Variable] => Expr = { case Seq(f1,f2) =>
      //do the addition for this field
    } 
    (args, retType, body)
}
```

For this function I can state properties such as:

```
val addAssociative: Expr = forall("x" :: F, "y" :: F, "z" :: F){ case (x, y, z) => 
    (x ^+ (y ^+ z)) === ((x ^+ y) ^+ z)
}
```

where `^+` is just the infix operator corresponding to add as presented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416106/defining-infix-operator-in-welder) other question.

What is a proper expression to insert in the body so that Inox does not assume anything on it while unrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about this:

1. Use a choose statement in the body of `addFunction`:

   ```
   val body: Seq[Variable] => Expr = {
     choose("r" :: F)(_ => E(true))
   }
   ```

   During unrolling, Inox will simply replace the `choose` with a fresh
   variables and assume the specified predicate (in this case `true`) on
   this variable.
2. Use a first-class function. Instead of using `add` as a named function,
   use a function-typed variables:

   ```
   val add: Expr = Variable(FreshIdentifier("add"), (F, F) =>: F)
   ```

   You can then specify your associativity property on `add` and prove the
   relevant theorems.

In your case, it's probably better to go with the second option. The issue with proving things about an `addFunction` with a choose body is that you can't substitute `add` with some other function in the theorems you've shown about it. However, since the second option only shows things about a free variable, you can then instantiate your theorems with concrete function implementations.

Your theorem would then look something like:

```
val thm = forallI("add" :: ((F,F) =>: F)) { add =>
  implI(isAssociative(add)) { isAssoc => someProperty }
}
```

and you can instantiate it through

```
val isAssocAdd: Theorem = ... /* prove associativity of concreteAdd */
val somePropertyForAdd = implE(
  forallE(thm)(\("x" :: F, "y" :: F)((x,y) => E(concreteAdd)()(x, y))), 
  isAssocAdd
)
```