# Strange precedence of operators >>= and >>

Tags: scala

Having:

```
case class A(x: Int) {
  def >>= (y: A) = A(x * y.x)
  def >> (y: A) = A(x + y.x)
}
```

Since `>>=` and `>>` both start with `>`, they should have the same precedence and left associativity.

However:

```
A(5) >>= A(3) >> A(2)
```

returns 25.

But should return 17, because:

```
A(5) >>= A(3) >> A(2) == (A(5) >>= A(3)) >> A(2) == 17
```

It looks like Scala compiler puts parantheses in the wrong place.

Bug?

Comment: I think all characters are considered, not just the first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922347/operator-precedence-in-scala#comment9218414_2922456) explains: operators which end with a `=` but don't start with one are considered assignment operators. They get the lowest precedence.
This rule is needed for operators such as `+=` and `*=`.

Comment: But these operators have nothing to do with assignment!

Comment: But they look like assignments. With mutable datastructures, for instance:
`val list = ListBuffer.empty[Int]; list += 3`
But I agree that Scala's precedence policy is not optimal :)