# Deciphering Scala code... JSON / Play framework / combinator / functional / tricks / OWrites

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm trying to understand every piece of the implementation of class OWritesOps explained here: http://kailuowang.blogspot.mx/2013/11/addremove-fields-to-plays-default-case.html

The way scala / play doc is structured doesn't really help (in this area Java(doc) beats Scala(doc) hands down).

Let's start with: addField:

```
def addField[T: Writes](fieldName: String, field: A => T): OWrites[A] = 
(writes ~ (__ \ fieldName).write[T])((a: A) => (a, field(a)))
```

I could only guess that the `~` is an equivalent of "and" (I gather it from here: http://mandubian.com/2012/10/01/unveiling-play-2-dot-1-json-api-part2-writes-format-combinators/ )

Alright, so let's just take it this way: `(writes ~ (__ \ fieldName).write[T])` create a new instance of `Writes` (combo).

What about `(__ \ fieldName)` ? After a lot of digging Play Doc, I came to a (shaky) conclusion that it produces an instance of JsPath? How did I arrive to that conclusion? It's for that `.write[T]` that follows; `JsPath` has that method.

Beside, I read somewhere that `__` is a shortcut for `JsPath` (I forgot where, I guess it's in Play Doc as well, but using Scala doc it's almost impossible to find my way back to that page).

Ok..., so `(writes ~ (__ \ fieldName).write[T])` produces an instance of `OWrites`. Next: what's this?: `((a: A) => (a, field(a)))`

Oh..., it's for the apply the parameter to the "apply" method of OWrites; it takes an lambda function with the following signature `((A) => JsObject)`

Ok...., so.... `(a, field(a))` is supposed to create an instance of `JsObject`. So, I opened the play doc, `JsObject`. Hmm..., I guess it's this constructor (?): `JsObject(fields: Seq[(String, JsValue)])` .... But,... I really doubt it.... I'm lost here.

Anyway, let's see an example how it is used:

```
val customWrites: Writes[Person] = Json.Writes[Person]. addField("isAdult", _.isAdult)
```

So..., `_.isAdult` is supposed to map to a block with the following signature: `A => T`  ... But..., if that's really the case, I was expecting `{x => x.isAdult}` .... so I guess `_.isAdult` is a syntactic-sugar provided by Scala (?).

So... back to the definition of `addField`: `field(a)` executes the block "_.isAdult". I can infer here that `a` is an instance of `Person` then.

Can you help me decipher all this?

Scala is cool, but it's doc system (still) sucks :(

Comment: What's your actual question? What can't you decipher?

Comment: I can't decipher this question :P Try to have some numbers for the question that you want to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Can you help me decipher all this?

### I could only guess that the ~ is an equivalent of "and"

`~` is the name of a method invoked on the instance of `OWrites`. `writes ~ (__ \ fieldName).write[T])` is the same as `writes.~((__ \ fieldName).write[T]))`. **Note** the brackets around the argument of `~`.

There are two things relevant to this equivalent form:

1. In Scala, any method with one argument can be written using **infix notation**. For example, if you have an instance `list: java.util.ArrayList[Int]`, you could write `list add 5`.
2. While a method name need not be alphanumeric (as in Java), not all operators have the same precedence. For example, `1 + 5 * 2` translates to `1.+(5.*(2))` and not to `1.+(5).*(2)`. [Here's a summary of operator precedence in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922456/4041697).

However, `OWrites` has no method called `~` in its interface. If you import `play.api.libs.functional.syntax._`, there's an implicit conversion

```
implicit def toFunctionalBuilderOps[M[_], A](a: M[A])(implicit fcb: FunctionalCanBuild[M]) = new FunctionalBuilderOps[M, A](a)(fcb)
```

and `FunctionalBuilderOps` defines the method

```
def ~[B](mb: M[B]): FunctionalBuilder[M]#CanBuild2[A, B] = {
  val b = new FunctionalBuilder(fcb)
  new b.CanBuild2[A, B](ma, mb)
}
```

and an alias for it: `def and[B](mb: M[B]): FunctionalBuilder[M]#CanBuild2[A, B] = this.~(mb)`

### What about (__ \ fieldName) ?

The package `play.api.libs.json` defines a value `val __ = JsPath`, so the double underscores are just an alias for the singleton object `JsPath`. The singleton object `JsPath` is not to be confused with the equally-named class. This construct is called a companion object in Scala. While Java puts static members next to the regular members in a class, Scala puts them inside the companion object.

Apparently, the object `JsPath` is at the same time the companion object of the case class `JsPath` and an instance of `JsPath(List.empty)`.

`fieldName` is of type `String` and `JsPath` defines a method

```
def \(child: String) = JsPath(path :+ KeyPathNode(child))
```

which is equivalent to

```
def \(child: String) = JsPath.apply(path :+ KeyPathNode(child))
```

The default apply method of a case class' companion object creates a new instance, so this is equivalent to

```
def \(child: String) = new JsPath(path :+ KeyPathNode(child))
```

As our singleton object `__` is an instance of `JsPath` with the empty list for `path`, this returns us a `new JsPath(KeyPathNode(child))`, where `child == fieldName`

### what's this?: ((a: A) => (a, field(a)))

It's a function taking an instance of `A`. The function maps the argument `a` to the tuple `(a, field(a)`, where `field` is a function provided as argument to your method `addField`. It has the signature `field: A => T`, so it is a function that takes an instance of `A` and returns an instance of `T`.

This may be a bit confusing, so let me give you an example function that does not operate on generics. Say you want to define a function `f` that squares an integer number. For example, `f(1)` should be `1`, `f(3)` should be `9`. As it takes an integer and returns an integer, its signature is `f: Int => Int`. It's implementation is `f = (x: Int) => x * x`.

### Oh..., it's for the apply the parameter to the "apply" method of OWrites; it takes an lambda function with the following signature ((A) => JsObject)

Actually, this is not correct - the signatures do not match. The given lambda function is of type `A => (A, T)`. Also, as pointed out in the first part of the answer, the method `~` returns an instance of `FunctionalBuilder#CanBuild2`. Unfortunatly, I am lost on what the called `apply`-method does, because it is highly generic and uses implicit arguments of a generic type.

### so I guess _.isAdult is a syntactic-sugar provided by Scala (?).

Yes, the underscore in lambda functions is syntactic sugar for capturing the arguments. For example, `_ + _` is syntactic sugar for `(x, y) => x + y`, meaning the following two values are equivalent:

```
val f: (Int, Int) => Int = (x, y) => x + y
val g: (Int, Int) => Int = _ + _
```

So `_.isAdult` really just translates to `{x => x.isAdult}` and in the example, `x: Person`.

## Update

The idea behind this write builder seems to be to provide means of defining a mapping from one of your Scala classes to JSON. Let's take a look again at the `case class Person(name: String, age: Int)`. Now, let's assume we have an instance of `Person`:

```
val odersky = Person("Martin Odersky", 56)
```

and want to serialize the instance to the following JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Martin Odersky", 
  "age": 56
}
```

The key is always a string, but the value can be of a different type. So, basically, the serialization is a function taking a `Person` and returning a tuple of key-value pairs where the value is always a string, i.e., `Person => ((String, String), (String, Int))`. Or, in the general case where we do not know what we are going to serialize, simply that it has two fields, it is `A => ((String, B), (String, C))` for arbitrary types `A`, `B`, and `C`.

This is what `CanBuild2` emulates - the `2` standing for the number of members to serialize. There's also a `CanBuild3`, `CanBuild4` and so on.

We can instantiate a `CanBuild2` that is appropriate to our example, by calling

```
val serializer = (__ \ "name").write[String] ~ (__ \ "age").write[Int]
```

Here, the type of `serializer` is `FunctionalBuilder[OWrites]#CanBuild2[String, Int]`

Now, the apply method of `CanBuild2` can be used to generate an instance of the first generic argument - `OWrites`. The argument to the apply method is a function that maps an instance of our type to serialize (here `Person`) to a tuple of the desired value types, here `String` and `Int` (representing `name` and `age`).

```
val personWriter: OWrites[Person] = serializer((p: Person) => (p.name, p.age))
```

This writer can now be used to generate a JSON string from any instance of `Person`. So we can pass our person and get the desired output:

```
println(toJson(odersky)(personWriter))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time understanding my confusion and clearing them up!

About that ~ I also was guessing it's in the play.api.libs.functional.syntax._ ... But I couldn't find the doc for that "play.api.libs.functional.syntax" to confirm my guess (in the Play doc api, all I could find was "play.api.libs.functional").... So I guessed further, maybe "syntax" it's a package object, but I couldn't find any reference to it in the doc of "play.api.libs.functional". ... I really hope Scala doc gets some improvements.

Comment: @user3443096 In this case I found the implicit conversion difficult to follow. Fortunatly, IntelliJ is good in resolving static method binding - even with implicits present - so `go to declaration` is a useful tool to find out which method is called statically.

Comment: As the writer said in his blog, not much doc around.... I made another guess: so... a Writes made up of N Writes will take a tuple with N elements. I looked for "apply" method in Writes, couldn't find one with tuple as param. So, I opened my scala console: 

First I try this: [code] val myComboWrites = ((__ \ "a").write[String] ~ (__ \ "b").write[Int]) [/code]

It gives: myComboWrites: play.api.libs.functional.FunctionalBuilder[play.api.libs.json.OWrites]#CanBuild2[String,Int] = play.api.libs.functional.FunctionalBuilder$CanBuild2@25a6a348

Next: [code] myComboWrites(("AAA", 2)) [/code] Error:

Comment: <console>:33: error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  [B](f: B => (String, Int))(implicit fu: play.api.libs.functional.ContravariantFunctor[play.api.libs.json.OWrites])play.api.libs.json.OWrites[B] <and>
  [B](f: (String, Int) => B)(implicit fu: play.api.libs.functional.Functor[play.api.libs.json.OWrites])play.api.libs.json.OWrites[B]
 cannot be applied to ((String, Int))
              myComboWrites(("AAA", 2))

Comment: Oh... it's this "apply" in OWrites: apply[A](f: (A) ⇒ JsObject): OWrites[A]

... It takes a function that turns an object of type A to an object of type JsObject ...

That's exactly why last night I made this guess that "(a, field(a))" is a way of instantiating a JsObject. But I wasn't very sure (no doc to confirm my guess).

Comment: Haha... I'm equally lost in this "apply" of OWrites.

Comment: This a small example, maybe can provide some hint:

val myComboWritesBuilder = ((__ \ "a").write[String] ~ (__ \ "b").write[Int]);
val myComboWrites = myComboWritesBuilder({a: String => (a, 2)});
toJson("dude") (myComboWrites);

Result: {"a":"dude","b":2}

Comment: After looking at this:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.functional.FunctionalBuilder

and this:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.functional.FunctionalBuilder$CanBuild2

My conclusion for now: This (combo) Writes "generated" by FunctionalBuilder really does take a tuple. It applies each writes in the combo to each element in the tuple.

I just hope Play-framework developers be more clear about this in their official doc (guide / tutorial).

Comment: This gives another hint: scala> val myComboWrites = myComboWritesBuilder({a: String => (a, 2)})
myComboWrites: play.api.libs.json.OWrites[String] = play.api.libs.json.OWrites$$anon$2@2304b17e

This special kind of "OWrites" (play.api.libs.json.OWrites$$anon$2) generates an anonymous class out of the tuple fed into it. This anonymous class generates "unapply" for the tuple.

I've also tried: val myTupleWriters = Json.writes[(String, Int)] : error: No apply function found matching unapply parameters. 
So, this magic OWrites$$anon$2 provides that "unapply" func to the tuple passed in as param.

Comment: @user3443096 I updated the answer to describe what I think is the usage of `CanBuild`. It's pretty hard to read your comments though, as code formatting does not work well in comments.

Comment: You answer needs to be starred :) It's a bag of tricks doc-ed.