# Scala not letting me add integers

Tags: scala, type-conversion, scala-implicits

Here's some code which looks reasonable enough to me:

```
val myMap: Map[Int, Int] = ((x: Int) => Map[Int, Int](1 -> x + 1, 2 -> x + 2))(4)
```

When I try to compile it, I get two errors like this:

```
Error:(20, 68) type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
    val myMap: Map[Int, Int] = ((x: Int) => Map[Int, Int](1 -> x + 1, 2 -> x + 2))(4)
                                                                   ^
```

I understand that my compiler is trying to use the string addition implementation of `+`. But why is it doing that? How do I ask the compiler to use integer addition here?

(Changing `Int` to `Integer` doesn't help.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simpler example that reproduces the error:

```
scala> def fail(x: Int) = 1 -> x + 1
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
       def fail(x: Int) = 1 -> x + 1
                                   ^
```

All of the operators in play are left-associative, so everything reads left-to-right. That is, the call chain looks like this:

```
1.->(x).+(1)
```

or using infix notation:

```
(1 -> x) + 1
```

`1 -> x` returns a tuple `(1, x)` and a tuple does not have a `+` method, so the compiler attempts to implicitly convert it to a `String` via `toString`, because `String` does have a `+` method, which eventually fails because `Int` is required.

Just use parentheses to group things appropriately:

```
scala> def foo(x: Int) = 1 -> (x + 1)
foo: (x: Int)(Int, Int)
```

Answer (score 1):

'->' [has the same precedence as](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922456/1644272) '+', so `1 -> x + 1` parses as `(1 -> x) + 1`. Adding parentheses as `1 -> (x + 1)` fixes this error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that according to [Scala's precedence rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922347/operator-precedence-in-scala/2922456#2922456), `->` binds as tightly as `+`, because it starts with `-`.

It's fixed by adding parentheses:

```
val myMap: Map[Int, Int] = ((x: Int) => Map[Int, Int](1 -> (x + 1), 2 -> (x + 2)))(4)
```