# eta/placholders underscores in scala: why does "Console println" work and "Console.println" not?

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand the exact details of when eta expansion happens and when param placeholders are expanded.

Going through many examples and SO answers/questions i understand the following:

```scala
val xs = (1 to 5)

/*ex1*/ xs.foreach(println)

/*ex2*/ xs.foreach(println _) // eta expansion?

/*ex3*/ xs.foreach(println(_)) // placeholder syntax

/*ex4*/ xs.foreach(println(_ * 2)) // INVALID -> xs.foreach(println(x => x * 2))

/*ex5*/ xs.foreach(Console.println _ * 2) // INVALID same reason?

/*ex6*/ xs.foreach(Console println _ * 2) // works
```

My quesion is: why does **ex6** work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> /*ex5*/ xs.foreach(Console.println _ * 2) // INVALID same reason?
> /*ex6*/ xs.foreach(Console println _ * 2) // works
> ```

We can try to construct the function value inside `foreach` (ex6):

```
val fun1: Int => Unit = x => Console println x * 2
val fun2: Int => Unit =      Console println _ * 2 // short form
```

Note that using infix syntax, Scala would expect exactly one argument to the right, so how comes that `x * 2` is (correctly) interpreted as a single argument? This is because the `*` symbol has [higher precedence in the infix notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922347/operator-precedence-in-scala#2922456). If we used an alphabetical method, it would not work:

```
val fun6: Int => Unit = x => Console println x max 2  // not allowed
```

So while ex6 works, we can't however write (ex5):

```
val fun3: Int => Unit = x => Console.println x * 2
```

Simply because that is **not valid Scala syntax**:

```
Console.println 3  // not possible, either infix or parentheses!
```

So we would have to introduce parentheses:

```
val fun4: Int => Unit = x => Console.println (x * 2)
```

But with the extra parentheses, you cannot use the underscore shortcut:

```
val fun5: Int => Unit =      Console.println (_ * 2)
```

(for the same reason of ex4).

Comment: Thanks! very well explained

Comment: @jen P.S. Looking at it again, there is indeed another tricky bit that makes `fun1` and `fun2` work, that is the precedence of the symbolic operator `*` which I am just seeing now. For example `x => Console println x max 2` does _not_ work.

Comment: I just figured that out as well. In  this case it is really better to use parenthesis. I am also wondering if there is really no way to make this work without infix (placeholders without infix). My gut feelings tells me impossible