# how to modify self-defined scala operators' precedence

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, operator-precedence

Is it possible to modify the precedence of any self-defined operators?
For example, I implement elementary arithmetic with totally self-defined operators.

```
  case class Memory(name:String){
    var num:Num = null

    def <<=(x:Num): Unit = {
      println(s"assign ${x.value}")
      this.num = x
    }
  }

  case class Num(var value:Int) {
    def +|+(x:Num) = {
      println("%d + %d = %d".format( value,x.value,x.value + value ))
      Num(value + x.value)
    }
    def *|*(x:Num) = {
      println("%d * %d = %d".format( value,x.value,x.value * value ))

      Num(value * x.value)
    }
  }


  val m1 = Memory("R")

  val a = Num(1)
  val b = Num(3)
  val c = Num(9)
  val d = Num(12)

  m1 <<= a *|* b +|+ c +|+ d *|* a

  println("final m1 ",m1.num.value)
```

The results are

```
1 * 3 = 3
3 + 9 = 12
12 * 1 = 12
12 + 12 = 24
assign 24
(final m1 ,24)
```

Apparently the precedence is correct. I want `*|*` be the same precedence as `*` and  `+|+` the same as `+`, `<<=` is equivalent as `=` as well. How scala figure it out?

Comment: @jwvh You are right. The order is exactly what I want. But I don't know how scala figure correct precedence out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question about modyfing operator precedence - to change it you basically just have to change the **first character** of your custom operator - this is how scala figures out precedense for infix operators, by just looking at the first character. So if you eg. add an operator `*|+`:

1. It will have same precedence as `*|*`, like with `*` and `*`.
2. "Bigger" precedence than `+|+`, just like with `*` and `+`.

Unfortunately there is no other way to deal with it right now. No custom annotations/weights and so on to avoid making reading code too fuzzy.

The precedence rules are very well summarized here - [Operator precedence in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922347/operator-precedence-in-scala).

About your issue though - you get the right results.

`*|*`, as well as `*` are left-associative operators and their *first character* is `*`, so they have equal precedense.

Your operation:

`a *|* b +|+ c +|+ d *|* a`

Translates to

`a * b + c + d * a`, which is `1 * 3 + 9 + 12 * 1`.

Applying standard precedence rules - `(a*b) + c + (d*a)` result is 24.

Comment: For completeness it's worth mentioning the exception to your rule above, that ops *ending* with a `:` are right-associative. This is for example, how the list cons operator (`::`) knows the type is `List` - it derives it from the last element, `Nil`.