# Operator precedence in scala behaves strange

Tags: scala, operator-precedence

I was experimenting with operator precedence in Scala, and there is something strange happening here:

```
class Op{
  def +(that:Op):Op={println("called +");this}
  def -(that:Op):Op={println("called -");this}
  def *(that:Op):Op={println("called *");this}
  def /(that:Op):Op={println("called /");this}
  def %(that:Op):Op={println("called %");this}
}

val op = new Op;
op+op-op*op/op%op ;
op+op*op ;
```

For the first line, the output is:

```
called +
called *
called /
called %
called -
```

(Notice `+` is called before `*`.) However, for the second line, the output is:

```
called *
called +
```

(`*` is called before `+`.) I believe from what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922347/operator-precedence-in-scala) that `*` should be called before `+`. Is there something I got wrong?

Comment: @puhlen there is nothing strange or buggy, calls are grouped by precedence and then evaluated from left to right, as expected, see the end of my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala groups the expression by precedence, then evaluates the groups strictly from left to right, thus adhering to the precedence.

Your second call is equivalent to

```
op.+(op.*(op))
```

which is evaluated from inside to outside.

The same with the first call:

```
op+op-op*op/op%op
```

which becomes, with precedence applied,

```
op+op-(op*op/op%op)
```

or

```
(op+op).-(op*op/op%op)
```

or

```
// 1     5    2     3     4
op.+(op).-(op.*(op)./(op).%(op))
```

Comment: Read the question, this is not what op is asking about.  op + op - op * op produces `+ * -` as it compiles to `op.+(op).-(op*(op))`

Comment: I understood the op to ask this

Comment: @puhlen what do you mean by "the entire expression"? I don't see any other way to sequence this. Scala does not assume commutativity, so it correctly refrains from evaluating the steps (2, 3, 4) before step 1, but sticks to strict left-to-right where applicable.

Comment: Yeah, I was confused, this is how it should be.